# TeXstudio + Latexmk won't compile (with OS X): "Error: Could not start command: ..."

Tags: texlive, compiling, texstudio, mac, latexmk

> **UPDATE**: John reported the bug in the TeXstudio forum, and they fixed it. The development version TeXstudio 2.10.9 (hg 5929:7315f2e5eed3) works, when you change the Latexmk command to "latexmk -pdf -silent -synctex=1 %"

I recently switched from Texmaker to TeXstudio (version 2.10.8). In Texmaker, I used to compile my document with Latexmk. In TeXstudio, however, the default Latexmk command returns an error message. I work with OS X Yosemite (version 10.10.5) and TeX Live. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

My build settings in TeXstudio (**Default compiler = Latexmk**):
[image: my build settings in TeXstudio: Default compiler = Latexmk]

And the corresponding command settings (**latexmk -dvi -silent %**):
[image: my command settings in TeXstudio: Latexmk = latexmk -dvi -silent %]

And this is the error I get:
[image]

The document compiles normally when I choose PdfLaTeX instead of Latexmk.
I have seen related posts on stackoverflow, but none these included a solution for Latexmk. Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

EDIT: As ig0774 suggested, I changed the path to `/usr/texbin/latexmk -dvi -silent %` and pressed OK. When reopening the settings of TeXstudio, the path was set back to `latexmk -dvi -silent %`. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `latexmk` command to start with `/usr/texbin/latexmk`. By default, `/usr/texbin` is not part of the PATH from GUI applications.

---

**Edit**

Alright, a better suggestion:

1. Quit TeXStudio completely
2. Open the file "~/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini" in a text editor (you can use `open -a TextEdit ~/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini` from the terminal or any other text editor you like).
3. Find the line that starts "`Tools\Commands\latexmk=`", replace everything to the right of the equals sign with `/usr/texbin/latexmk -dvi %`
4. Launch TeXStudio

This should make the necessary change and persist it across restarts (hopefully... at least it works for me...)

Comment: see my edit above

Comment: @pipomas: Definitely looks like a bug to me. I get the same behaviour. This isn't... great, but as long as you're on Yosemite (not El Capitan) and you can run `sudo`, you could try running this command from the terminal: `sudo ln -s /usr/texbin/latexmk /usr/bin/latexmk`. This creates a link that adds `latexmk` to a folder available on the `$PATH` that TeXStudio sees, so it will be able to find `latexmk` despite the setting not saving.

Comment: I ran the command from the terminal, deleted all auxiliary files and try to compile with Latexmk. I got this error message
`Process started: latexmk -dvi -silent "test"
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'latex'
sh: latex: command not found Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages): latex: (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'test.log' Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'test': (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'test.log' Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing, unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.`

Comment: @pipomas: See my edit above. May as well delete the link, `sudo rm /usr/bin/latexmk`.

Comment: I changed the line to `Tools\Commands\latexmk=/usr/texbin/latexmk -dvi %`, saved it, reopened TeXstudio, deleted all auxiliary files, selected Latexmk as default compiler, tried to compile it and still it returns the same error.

Comment: @pipomas: This may be the time to rethink using `latexmk` with TeXStudio on OS X. That said, you *could* try modifying the command in the ini file to `/usr/texbin/latexmk -dvi -latex="/usr/texbin/latex %O %S" %`, but you'll have to make analogous changes for any other executable you use, e.g. `biber`, `bibtex`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually a bug in the way TeXStudio 2.10.8 under OS-X sets the PATH environment variable used for finding executables.

## Work around

In your `~/.profile` file add the following line at the end

```
export PATH=DUMMY1:$PATH:DUMMY2
```

(If you don't have a `~/.profile` file, create one containing the above line.)

Then restart TeXStudio, and you should find that it will run latexmk properly with the default settings of TeXStudio.

## Bug and its diagnosis

The bug is that the TeXStudio (in v. 2.10.8 under OS-X) sets its PATH variable as the concatenation of the following:

1. Any output produced by your `~/.profile` file.
2. The actual intended PATH variable.
3. A new line.
4. Any customizations done by TeXStudio.

It's the new line that's the killer.  If, as on my system, the location of TeXLive executables, `/Library/TeX/texbin` is the last item in the PATH, then that element is replaced by the same string followed by a new line character.  The result is that the TeXLive executables are no longer found.  The work around I suggested above insulates you from this problem.

A useful way of diagnosing these problems is to put the following line in one of `latexmk`'s configuration files, e.g., `latexmkrc` in the document directory:

```
warn "PATH = '$ENV{PATH}'\n";
```

Then after you run `latexmk` from TeXStudio, the Messages window will show the value of the PATH variable.

Comment: I don't have a `~/.profile` file. Can you please explain how to create one and where to save it exactly?

Comment: It's .profile in your home directory.  You can use any editor that can save plain text files with any name.  TeXstudio will do it: In the Save or Save As menu, you need to set the file type to "All files (*)".  To open such a file with a name beginning with a period from the File Open menu you need to do shift/cmd . to be able to see such files, which are normally hidden.

Comment: Here ist what I did: (1) created a `.profile` file containing `export PATH=DUMMY1:$PATH:DUMMY2` (2) saved it in the same folder where my `test.tex` file is. (3) opened TeXStudio, changed default compiler to Latexmk. (4) compiled the file. (5) still returns `Error: Could not start the command: latexmk -dvi -silent "test"`

Comment: The .profile file should be in your home directory.

Comment: I used `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` so find my home directory and  put it here: `~/Library/texmf/tex/.profile`, but still no luck.

Comment: Thanks John for reporting the bug on https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1700/. With the developer version of TeXstudio (2.10.9 (hg 5929:7315f2e5eed3)), Latemk compiles with no trouble.

Comment: I just noticed: Latexmk produces no pdf file. I get a .aux, .dvi, .fdb_latexmk, .fls, and .log file. But no pdf.

Comment: SOLVED: I had to use the pdf-variant of the command: "latexmk -pdf -silent -synctex=1 %"